# Google node authentication not storing user details to db

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js google strategy to authenticate and login to application. Login attempt is working perfectly but user details is not storing in DB. I didn't mention anything in models of UserSchema. I tried like below.

### api.js

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID        : config.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : config.googleAuth.callbackURL
    passReqToCallback   : true
},
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                var newUser          = new User();

                newUser.google.id    = profile.id;
                newUser.google.token = token;
                newUser.google.name  = profile.displayName;
                newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));

    
router.get('/pages/auth/loginWithGoogle', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect : '/invite-friends',
    failureRedirect : '/pages/auth/login'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
...
newUser['google.id']    = profile.id;
newUser['google.token'] = token;
newUser['google.name']  = profile.displayName;
newUser['google.email'] = profile.emails[0].value;
...
```

Comment: Its not working.I am not getting my controller inside to the GoogleStrategy function.